# AutoIncrement Array in an Array() : Is that possible?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I would like to do that :

```
$product[] = Array (
                            "article_title" => valeures,
                            "article_id" => ,
                            "article_value" => ,
                            "article_price" =>
                            "article_picture1" => ,
                            "article_picture2" => ,
                            "article_picture3" => ,
                            "article_picture4" => ,
                            "article_friends[]" => array ( "name" => ,
                                                    ),

                        );
```

But I know it won't work, I've been looking for hours on the net and on php.net, but I don't know how to do.
What I want to do, is getting a product[] array that can handle product[1]; product [2] ... and inside it, I got the same process : the "article_firends[]" will be autoincremented to do something like that :

In product[1] : artcile_friends[1][name] = John ; article_freidns[2][name] = Nina ... and so on with product[2] ...

This has been implementedin a foreach loop so it Should manage the keys automatically ..
How can I build it ?

Many Thanks, 
Miles

Comment: So....was there a question somewhere in there?

Comment: well .. yeah, I'm looking for the right way to write it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"article_friends[]" => array ( "name" => ,
```

doesn't create a new `article_friends` sub array. It creates a key in the parent $product array whose name happens to be `article_friends[]`.

Remove the quotes from around the key, so you end up with

```
article_friends[] => array ( "name" => , ...
```

Comment: I'm trying to test this.. Are you saying `$products[] = array( article_friends[] => array ("name" => "test") );` should work?

Answer (score 0):

This totally does work.

You're getting an error because of `valeures`, either this is a variable, than add a '$' or it's a string, than add quotes.
`"article_friends[]" => array ( "name" => ,` is wrong too, you have to add a value after "name".

The trailing comma in the 'article_friends[]' line should be omitted to.

Comment: Thanks, When I put Valeures I meant Values, like the value I want it to take, I know I have to put some variables in there, but will the article_firends[] will autoincrement each time I update the $product array to put another article_friends[] ?

Comment: no, "article_friends[]" is a string, therefore it acts like a normal key in your array. assuming you want to store a list of friends there,  you can do something like this: `...."article_friends" => array ( "name1", "name2", "name3" )...`